# Selecting from multiple tables with same where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm getting error:

> Column 'season' in where clause is ambiguous

and can't figure out how to fix it.

```
$fg_leader_id_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats_pd, stats_int, stats_ha, stats_ke, stats_ka, stats_kn, stats_lv, stats_sv, stats_snv WHERE `season`='".$season."' ORDER BY fgm/fga DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

I need to get rows from each table where column season equals `$season`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$fg_leader_id_query = mysql_query("
SELECT * 
FROM stats_pd, stats_int, stats_ha, stats_ke, stats_ka, stats_kn, stats_lv, stats_sv, stats_snv  
WHERE 
        `stats_pd.season`='".$season." OR
        `stats_int.season`='".$season." OR
        `stats_ha.season`='".$season." OR
        `stats_ke.season`='".$season." OR
        `stats_ka.season`='".$season." OR
        `stats_kn.season`='".$season." OR
        `stats_lv.season`='".$season." OR
        `stats_sv.season`='".$season." OR
        `stats_snv.season`='".$season."' 
ORDER BY fgm/fga DESC LIMIT 1
") or die(mysql_error());
```